# How to extract every possible date within a text?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following text blob:

> “They’re doing a ballet,” says Adam Ellison, a materials scientist at
>   the company, watching the furnace workers as the glass dumps
>   brimstone-like heat into the surrounding air. “It’s hot as hell, the
>   glass 23 october 2003 gets stiff very quickly, and you can only work
>   with it for a few minutes,” he says. Ellison would know—he helped
>   develop the material they’re pouring, which is 19 November 2003
>   branded Gorilla Glass and is October 17, 2011 found on many
>   smartphones because it is tough, thin, and 19 November 200000003
>   lightweight 41 january 1098.

I would like to create a regex that extract all the possible dates formats. For example the regex must extract:

```
23 october 2003
19 November 2003
October 17, 2011
```

For the above I tried with the following：

```
((\d+).(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December).(\d+))
```

However I do not get how to match blank spaces, lower and upper cases (`?:`) and particularly this format `October 17, 2011`. Any idea of how to get the desired previous output?.

Comment: Try adding the `i` and `g` flags

Comment: Does the position matter?... could you provide an example? @bejado?... thanks for the comment!

Comment: @tumbleweed Can you show your existing python code?

Comment: its just the regex... I was planning to use pandas: `df['text'].str.findall(r"((\d+).(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December).(\d+))").apply(', '.join)` @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from dateutil import parser
import re

a = """“They’re doing a ballet,” says Adam Ellison, a materials scientist at the company, watching the furnace workers as the glass dumps brimstone-like heat into the surrounding air. “It’s hot as hell, the glass 23 october 2003 gets stiff very quickly, and you can only work with it for a few minutes,” he says. Ellison would know—he helped develop the material they’re pouring, which is 19 November 2003 branded Gorilla Glass and is October 17, 2011 found on many smartphones because it is tough, thin, and 19 November 200000003 lightweight 41 january 1098."""
b = re.findall(r'\S+ \S+ (?=\d{4}\b)\d{4}', a)
print b
tl = []
for c in b: 
    try:
        if parser.parse(c):
            tl.append(c)
    except:
        pass
print tl
```

Output:

```
['23 october 2003', '19 November 2003', 'October 17, 2011', '41 january 1098']
['23 october 2003', '19 November 2003', 'October 17, 2011']
```

---

Although this is not the best solution, but it works:

```
from IPython.display import display as dp
import pandas as pd
import re

a="""“They’re doing a ballet,” says Adam Ellison, a materials scientist at the company, watching the furnace workers as the glass dumps brimstone-like heat into the surrounding air. “It’s hot as hell, sdkhfks BDR 1990  the glass 23 october 2003 gets stiff very quickly, and you can only work with it for a few minutes,” he says. Ellison would know—he helped develop the material they’re pouring, which is 19 November 2003 branded Gorilla Glass and is October 17, 2011 found on many smartphones because it is tough, thin, and 19 November 200000003 lightweight 41 january 1098. 31 february 1990 sdkhfks AB 1990. """

def foo(a):
    b = re.findall(r'\S+ \S+ (?=\d{4})\d{4}\b', a)
    tl = []
    for c in b: 
        try:
            if pd.tseries.tools.parse_time_string(c):
                tl.append(c)
        except:
            pass
    return tl

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'c1': [a, a]})
dp(df)
df['valid_dates'] = df.c1.apply(lambda x: foo(str(x)))
dp(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks but for this time I am not planning to use date time... I will wrangle my data again..

Comment: @tumbleweed Check now. Is it better?

Comment: @tumbleweed But it will fail for `30 February 2001`. https://regex101.com/r/bSRNpZ/6

Comment: @tumbleweed Apart from `30 February`, you will also have to check for leap years for valid date. For eg, `29 February 2017` is not valid but `29 February 2016` is valid.

Comment: Yes but your regex is returning me weird string like: `jkhkjkkk (XB 1890`

Comment: @tumbleweed Yes but `parser.parse()` will throw error for that weird string and won't append it to `tl`. You will get all the valid dates in the `tl` list.

Comment: Sure... so do what can I do in order to do not return irrelevant strings?

Comment: @tumbleweed Why do you care about the regex when you are getting all the valid dates in `tl` list. Isn't it what you require?

Comment: The problem is that with your regex I got strings that aren't dates (e.g. `jkhkjkkk (XB 1890`)

Comment: @tumbleweed Sure but that will be discarded. It's unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just want to extract the dates in a pandas dataframe. When I tested it it wasnt discarted it.

Comment: For example:  `['Gdfsdfn AC 1990', '12 January 2004']`

Comment: @tumbleweed Can you include `print df.head()` or dataframe setup in the question so I can copy the the dataframe on work on it?

Comment: Here is the issue: https://regex101.com/r/QXymQZ/1 Sorry if I wasn't clear!

Comment: As you can see it is actually matching strings that aren't dates like: `sdkhfks AB 1990 `

Comment: @tumbleweed Check now.

Comment: @tumbleweed For pandas questions including dataframe setup and final required dataframe makes it easier to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you explicitly need month names?

```
(?:[1-3][0-9]\s\w+|\w+\s[1-3][0-9]),?\s[0-9]+
```

So

- **(** `[1-3][0-9]` dates (not exactly 01-31)
- `\s\w+` space + word **)**
- OR
- **(** word + space + dates **)**
- `,?` optional comma + space
- one or more numbers.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T4Bdk0/1)

I think 01-31 would be something like `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`, but then you mention "possible dates", so 31 February wouldn't be "possible"...

Comment: It's a date, so stick it where you think it should go ;) I'll let you figure that out

Comment: It seems that I also got false positives: `38 DUB 29875954`, that's why I tried setting all the months... any idea of how to  escape the false positives?... So yes I need explicitly month names..

Comment: Just replace `\w+` with the list of months that you had, then

Comment: I tried to modify it like this: `(?:[1-3][1-9]+|(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)+|(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)+\s[1-3][1-9]),?\s[0-9]+`

Comment: `[1-3][1-9]` does not match the 10th of any month... [Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/kB7lhl/1)

Comment: Just another thing... the last regex works just for this type: October 17, 2011. However for the other formats (23 october 2003, 19 November 2003) it doesn't return anything... why is this happening?. Also, I got false positives: check this for example: https://regex101.com/r/bSRNpZ/5

Answer (score 1):

Given that text, you can get the dates like so:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\b(?:[1-3][0-9]\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[12][0-9]{3})|(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s[1-3][0-9],\s?[12][0-9]{3})\b)', txt)
['23 october 2003', '19 November 2003', 'October 17, 2011']
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/yjtPE0/3)

Comment: This actually works in regex101, however in my dataframe it returns nothing. Any ida idea of why this is happening?.

Comment: I applied the regex like this: `#df['col'] = df['text'].str.findall('(\b(?:[1-3][0-9]\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[12][0-9]{3})|(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s[1-3][0-9],\s?[12][0-9]{3})\b)').apply(', '.join)
` and it is not returning anything...

Comment: If I construct a dataframe with that text, and have `pat=r'(\b(?:[1-3][0-9]\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[12][0-9]{3})|(?:[a-zA-Z]+\s[1-3][0-9],\s?[12][0-9]{3})\b)'` then run ` df[0].str.findall(pat)` it returns the same matches expected. Perhaps your dataframe is not acting on a series?

Comment: how can I know if it is acting on a series?

Comment: `type(df['text'])` should tell you Series vs something else. I don't know Pandas that well, but I have run across the regex needs to be against a series...

Comment: It is actually a series: `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: Also I got issues with the year, it has a false positive check this: https://regex101.com/r/bSRNpZ/2

Comment: I don't know then. Works here. Version of Pandas?

Comment: I have '0.19.2' @dawg

Comment: That is not the same regex I have. But try `((?:\b[1-3][0-9]\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)|(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\s[1-3][0-9],\s?[12][0-9]{3}\b))` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bSRNpZ/3)

Comment: again I got anything... with: `df['text'].str.findall('((?:\b[1-3][0-9]\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[12][0-9]{3}\b)|(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\s[1-3][0-9],\s?[12][0-9]{3}\b))').apply(', '.join)`

Comment: Try a simple regex just to see if there text is being processed. Try df['text'].str.findall(r'\d+')` Also, make sure your regex is a raw string `r'pattern' or you need to re-escape it.

Comment: It is actually working.. it returned all the numbers, furthermore this is not the only regex I am using.

Comment: I suppose ask a new question then if it is not working. Rgexes don't get much attention in Pandas. Best of luck!